# Loop over subgroups

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I am trying to make a loop with an `if` statement, I want to get estimates for different groups.

This is a toy example.

```
 use auto.dta

local Pobl  `"if foreign==0"' `"if foreign==0 & trunk>5"'  
foreach grupo in `Subpoblacion' {
        display  "Grupo:" "`grupo'"
        sum  price  `grupo'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
foreach  v in "foreign==0"  "foreign==0 & trunk>5"  {
   sum  price if  `v'
}
```

Comment: Note that the example is not especially convincing as you've replaced two lines with three -- but the principle is right.